# How to run a java web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

I have a folder that has only .java files. There are no .html, .jsp, .jsf etc. files only .java. I was told that this is a web application, but I have no idea on how to run it.

Here is a sample code from one of the .java files:

```
public List<String> generateHtml(String name, String css) {
    List<String> html = new ArrayList<>();
    html.add("<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"" + css
            + "\"/></head><body>");
    html.add("<div class='screen page_size " + name + "'>");
    for (HtmlElement element : orderedElements) {
        element.generateHtml(html);
    }
    html.add("</div>");
    html.add("</body></html>");
    return html;
}
```

I tried making a web project in eclipse and importing the files and running it, but no luck. It gives me a lot of errors with something to do with `jetty`. After installing jetty it still didnt work. Maybe I am installing it wrong. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Please provide more information. Web applications are usually meant to be run on a web server like Tomcat (or in your case, Jetty) so you need to deploy it on that server, then access its URL.

Comment: this looks to me as a "self-written" webapp, since it really generates html in your code fragment; if so, there must be a main class, which contains a main method, which you can run calling java. Of course you have to provide proper classpath.

Comment: @dasAnderlausMinga there is a main method, but when I run it it gives the errors about jetty.

Comment: i guess you have to provide more details. maybe you should upload your project to e.g. github. At leat post the content of your main method class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a runnable war with jetty, have a look a the [Embedded Jetty examples](http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedded-examples.html#embedded-minimal-servlet)

You can call the generateHtml method from the servlet below.

```
package org.eclipse.jetty.embedded;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler;

public class MinimalServlets
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
        server.setHandler(handler);


        handler.addServletWithMapping(HelloServlet.class, "/*");


        server.start();
             server.join();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        @Override
        protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request,
                              HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException,
                                                            IOException
        {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            //From here you can call the generateHtml method
            response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello from HelloServlet</h1>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider giving an answer yourself instead of only providing a link to it, because in this form, if the link becomes obsolete, so does your answer. Instead summarize the answer in the link yourself and provide the link for further information/ressource.

Comment: Thanks, I expanded the answer.

Comment: which folder do i save this file?

Comment: Next to your other source in the folder structure org/eclipse/jetty/embedded